# How to use block and thread dimension for processing of 2D image

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I'm currently working on processing an image (2D array) that is read in as a binary file and should be 512x4096 with CUDA. My question is how am I to handle the specific indices (with respect to blocks and threads) when everything is really stored as a 1D array. As an example, I'm trying to create a function that circshifts everythin to the right by . My code is

```
//CircShift, without scaling
__global__ void circShift(cufftComplex* input, cufftComplex* output, int numK, int numA) {
    int w = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int h = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    if ((h < numA) && (w < numK)) {
        int idx = h * numK + w;
        if (w+1<numK) {
            output[h*numK+w+1].x = input[idx].x;
            output[h*numK+w+1].y = input[idx].y;
        } else {
            output[h*numK].x = input[idx].x;
            output[h*numK].y = input[idx].y;
        }


    }

}
```

My current blockdim is (256, 64) and my threaddim is (16,8).

I am wondering if this is the correct way to implement something like this in terms of indexing. Would my w be equivalent to the column #, and would my h be equivalent to the row number. Let us say I am using something like python and load the image as a 2D array M. Is indexing in CUDA via h*numK+w correct for trying to access M[h][w].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing seems correct assuming the image matrix has a **row major** ordering: `w` will give you the absolute x coordinate in the image (or column number) and `h*numK+w` is equivalent to `y * imageWidth + x` which is a common idiom in accessing cells in CUDA. Just make sure your entire image grid is covered (you just wrote 512x4096, I assume 4096 is the image width).

As a sidenote you should access your `cufftComplex` elements once per thread instead of duplicating your `operator[]` access code (also as a refactoring point).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you elaborate more on the side note?

Comment: @Jason Sure, I meant reading a `cufftComplex` once instead of accessing the same location twice for `x` and `y`. That would probably guarantee better memory coalescing and avoid some unnecessary readings (although the compiler might optimize it anyway).

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Thank you!